# react native android error after upgrade to 0.67.2 - SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: react-native

I have just upgraded from RN 0.63.3 to 0.67.2...and Im now receiving an error when I try to clean project in Android studio

```
....node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:350  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {                 ^SyntaxError: Unexpected token =    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)    at Object.<anonymous> (....node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\shared\output\bundle.js:12:16)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
```

If you look at the file path its referring to (`node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:350`)...this is the line of code where its unhappy

```
  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {
    this._processRequest(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading node to latest version fixed the issue